# Problems with sorting table Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have a table and use tablesort plugin with it, the table sorts the data already in the table but will not sort any new data I add. Desperate for a fix of this problem. Any different methods or even a whole different table would be great, just as long as I can sort all the data correctly.

```
 !DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/theme1.min.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />


    <script src="jqm/demos/js/jquery.js">
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="__jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 

    <script src="jqm/demos/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js">
    </script>


        <script>


            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btn1').on('click', AddScore);
                $("#myTable").tablesorter();



            });

            function AddScore() {
                var jqTableBody = $('#myTable tbody');
                var sTRTemplate = '<tr>' +

                                  '    <td>{Id}</td>' +
                                  '    <td>{Course}</td>' +
                                  '    <td>{Target}</td>' +
                                  '    <td>{Points}</td>' +
                                  '</tr>';

                var sTRAppend = sTRTemplate;

                $('div[data-role="fieldcontain"] input:text').each(function () {
                    switch (this.id) {

                        case 'ScoreID': sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{Id}', this.value); break;
                        case 'ScoreCourse': sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{Course}', this.value); break;
                        case 'ScoreTarget': sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{Target}', this.value); break;
                        case 'ScorePoints': sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{Points}', this.value); break;
                    }
                })
                jqTableBody.append(sTRAppend);
            }


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
         <h1>Current Top 10</h1>


<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="ScoreID">Column 1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ScoreID" id="ScoreID" value=""  />
</div>  
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="ScoreCourse">Column 2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ScoreCourse" id="ScoreCourse" value=""  />
</div>  

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="ScoreTarget">Column 3:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ScoreTarget" id="ScoreTarget" value=""  />
</div>  
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="ScorePoints">Column 4:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ScorePoints" id="ScorePoints" value=""  />
</div>  
        <button id="btn1">Add</button>



    <table data-role="table" id="myTable" class="tablesorter" data-mode="columntoggle" border="1" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
      <thead>
        <tr>

       <th>Student ID</th>
          <th data-priority="3">Course</th>
          <th data-priority="1">Target</th>
          <th data-priority="5">Score (pts)</th>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>

          <td>Bg10xb</td>
          <td>golf</td>
          <td>101</td>
          <td>229</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>Bg12we</td>
          <td>tennis</td>
          <td>200</td>
          <td>201</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>Bg56gf</td>
          <td>football</td>
          <td>91</td>
          <td>194</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont know how this plugin works. Either keep all data in an array, sort it, empty table, and put all back. Or do what @Mottie says :-)

Answer (score 0):

After the new rows are appended, make sure to trigger an update on the table so tablesorter knows to refresh its cached data.

```
jqTableBody.append(sTRAppend);
// add the code below
$("#myTable").trigger('update');
```

In addition, there are a few issues with the code posted above:

- Missing left bracket in the `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- Missing `</tr>` before the closing `</thead>`
- Extra `<tr>` before the closing `</tbody>`

It may not seem like a big deal, but try using that HTML in IE...